# open dialog dynamically from href

Tags: jquery

I am trying to open a dialog from an anchor tag.
my html is:

```
<head>
    <title>show dynamic dialog box in jquery</title>
    <link href="style/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/my_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:400px;height:600px;">
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Save" /> // this works!
<!--a href="#dialog" id ="Button1">Open</a-->// this is the line I want to use
</div>
</body>
</html>

my_script.js is:
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
        $("input:button").click(function() {
            var NewDialog;
            var _id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (_id === "Button1") {
                NewDialog = $('<div class="popup" title="PITCH">\
                Pitch is the relationship between a note and it\'s fundamental requency.</div>');
            }
            NewDialog.dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                show: 'clip',
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

my question is: how can I do this using the anchor tag as in the commented out line:
Open</a-->

This has been driving me nuts for three days and I have searched many times for an answer. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @intracept's answer is what you should be looking at - it sounds like you're forgetting to prevent the default action of the anchor (`event.preventDefault();`) - a button input doesn't change the browsers location like an anchor does which is why you find that it works.

Comment: What a quick reply.However I answered my own question within minutes of posting the original!

Comment: Nice one - post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @scrowler Feel free to vote up my answer ;)

Comment: I tried to vote up your answer, but I got a message saying I could not vote up for my own post. Nevertheless I am grateful for your reply.

Comment: @intracept get out it you cheeky one! :-)

Comment: @user3617351 You can click on the tick under my answer to accept it. :)

Comment: @scrowler LOL!  What!? ;)

Comment: If your problem has been successfully solved by the provided answer, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use something like:

```
$("#Button1").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    NewDialog = $('<div class="popup" title="PITCH">\
        Pitch is the relationship between a note and it\'s fundamental requency.</div>');
    }
    NewDialog.dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        show: 'clip',
        buttons: {
            "Close": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I replaced this line $("input:button").click(function(){
with
$("#Button1").click(function(){

and in my web page set the call to: <a href="#dialog" id ="Button1">Open</a>

Button1 could be any id, I used it from my original attempt to get this working.

Comment: Did you need the `event.preventDefault()` on your hyperlink?

Comment: No, but then I do not know what event.preventDefault() does. I am a long way from being an expert in javascript although I am quite competent in using C++ which is my main programming language.

Comment: Simply put, `event.preventDefault()` stops the default behaviour of the element from being performed.  So on a hyperlink, it stops the hyperlink from being followed.  If you are using your <a> then I'm surprised that you don't need it.  Because you do :)

Comment: intracept: thanks for your answer. I have now added  event.preventDefault() and it still works, so I will accept your recommendation and leave it in. Thanks again.